# Advantages of having a first class system and possibility of transforming a system into a first class one

Tags: gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I have two questions regarding [first class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint) systems.

1. What are the advantages of having a first class Hamiltonian (a Hamiltonian whose all constraints are first class) in a theory or having a first class gauge system to work? Or vice versa, what are the disadvantages of having a theory that is not first class?
2. Is it possible to transform a given Hamiltonian into a first class Hamiltonian or is it an intrinsic property and cannot be change?

Any help and explanation will be appreciated.

---

**A RELATED QUESTION:**

Another question arises in my mind now. If we have a second class constraint in our theory, do we loose gauge freedom? Or in a more proper format: How do gauge freedom and first/second class constraints related?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Consider adding a definition of a _first class Hamiltonian_ and possibly some references to ensure that everyone is on the same page.

Comment: Actually now I wonder what will change if I define first class Hamiltonian as

1) a function $H(q,p)$ such that $\{ H, \phi_j \} \approx 0$ for all the constraints $\phi_j$ of the theory

OR

2) a Hamiltonian whose all constraints are first class.

What possibly may change in the answers of my questions above in either case?

Comment: Assuming that we have already identified all constraints of the theory, then condition (1) is automatically satisfied, since if not, then there would be additional secondary constraints. The case (2) is already known as a _first class system._

Comment: Alright, I will edit my question by defining a first class Hamiltonian as in case (2) in a moment. Thanks for the clarity.